# Error handling in modern Cocoa applications

Tags: cocoa, exception, error-handling

I am a computer science student and I am about to finish soon.
We now have to code a complete application in the language of our choice.
We chose Objective-C because we all are Mac people.

There are a few things that have to be done to make our professors happy :-)
One assignment is:

Choose a methodology to handle the errors in your application.
Make sure all errors that could occur are handled properly!

Since the very beginning of our course we've been learning Java.
So we know that the Java guys do most of their error handling with exceptions.

I've read through a lot of resources and documents online. I also read Aaron Hillegass's book "Cocoa programming for Mac OS X". I (almost) never read anything about exceptions in the context of Cocoa programming.

What I would like to know is how you guys implement error-handling in your Objective-C code? I of course handled my errors somehow until now, but there was no concept behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective C, exceptions are intended to be used for fatal errors that usually indicate programmer error. Routine error handling in the Cocoa frameworks is typically handled by passing around NSError objects. Methods that may suffer errors accept NSErrors as arguments. In the event of an error, they will fill out the error that was passed to them. It is then the responsibility of the calling code to examine the error and act appropriately.

For further reading see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html